# Why in the TikZ code it produces two similar side by side results where shift is set 0 cm

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, sorting, intersections

In this code below

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\clip (-0.5,-0.75) rectangle (3.25,2.25); 
\foreach \pathname/\shift in {line/0cm, curve/2cm}{ \tikzset{xshift=\shift} 
\draw [->, name path=curve] (1,1.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (2,0.5) .. (0,0); 
\draw [->, name path=line](0,-.5) -- (1,2) ; \fill [name intersections={of=line and curve,sort by=\pathname, name=i}] [red, opacity=0.5, every node/.style={left=.25cm, black, opacity=1}] \foreach \s in {1,2,3} {(i-\s) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize\s}}; 
} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here in case of `\pathname line` shift is set 0cm but why it is showing this result?[image]

And also i am a bit confused what actually the code means in this part

```
\foreach \pathname/\shift in {line/0cm, curve/2cm}{ \tikzset{xshift=\shift} 
\draw [->, name path=curve] (1,1.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (2,0.5) .. (0,0); 
\draw [->, name path=line](0,-.5) -- (1,2) ; \fill [name intersections={of=line and curve,sort by=\pathname, name=i}] [red, opacity=0.5, every node/.style={left=.25cm, black, opacity=1}] \foreach \s in {1,2,3} {(i-\s) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize\s}}; 
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. What is your question ? Is this why there is a shift to the right?

Comment: The shift if for the curve not for the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the example under the documentation of option `/tikz/intersection/sort by=<path name>` in PGF manual.

Without any `\foreach`, the left side can be drawn by

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \draw[->, name path=curve] (1,1.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (2,0.5) .. (0,0); 
  \draw[->, name path=line] (0,-.5) -- (1,2); 
  \fill
    [name intersections={of=line and curve, sort by=line, name=i}]
    [red, opacity=0.5, every node/.style={left=.25cm, black, opacity=1}] 
    (i-1) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize1} 
    (i-2) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize2}
    (i-3) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize3};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

With the inner `\foreach`, three `circle`s can be drawn with

```
\fill[name intersections={..., name=i}] [...]
  \foreach \s in {1,2,3}
    { (i-\s) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize\s} };
```

To show the effect of option `sort by`, this example needs to show how `sort by=line` and `sort by=curve` effects the numbering of intersections. This leads to the right side. In order to put two drawings side by side, the following structure is used:

```
% left side
\tikzset{xshift=0cm} % useless
\draw[..., name path=curve] ...
\draw[..., name path=line ] ...
\fill[name intersections{..., sort by =line}] ...

% right side
\tikzset{xshift=2cm} % shift every following drawings to right by 2cm
\draw[..., name path=curve] ...
\draw[..., name path=line ] ...
\fill[name intersections{..., sort by =curve}] ...
```

The similarity between left and right sides lead to the outer `\foreach`.

Comment: Thanks now i understood the problem. Well explained

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of the foreach loop allows to iterate on several variables.
Here, the loop iterates on two variables named `\pathname` and `\shift`.  This latter variable defines the horizontal shift to the right through `\tikzset{xshift=\shift}`.

The name chosen in the loop `{line/0cm, curve/2cm}` is actually unrelated to the path names  `name path=curve` and `name path=line` as shown in the following example where I modified these names: `{lin/0cm, cur/1cm, lol/2cm}`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
%\clip (-0.5,-0.75) rectangle (3.25,2.25); 
\foreach \pathname/\shift in {bin/0cm, cur/1cm, lol/2cm, gag/3cm}{ \tikzset{xshift=\shift} 
\draw [->, name path=curve] (1,1.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (2,0.5) .. (0,0); 
\draw [->, name path=line](0,-.5) -- (1,2) ; 
\fill [name intersections={of=line and curve,%sort by=\pathname,
 name=i}] [red, opacity=0.5, every node/.style={left=.25cm, black, opacity=1}] 
\foreach \s in {1,2,3} {(i-\s) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize\s}}; 
} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```